# Trying to center align Ebay template - but doesn't work

Tags: html, css

Ok so I'm trying to create an Ebay template for my ebay listings and I am working out the kinks, any help would be GREATLY appreciated. I am trying to center my template in my listing's description so that way it is centered no matter what size the screen is at. I see other listing have it so I know its possible I just can't figure it out.

right now, as it is, the listing is sitting on the left hand side of the page. I need it to be centered. When I added the code `<div align="center">` it worked in preview, but when I actually accepted the revisions, the template was lost in a giant sea of white and you had to scroll through miles of white to find it.

I need to some how reduce the size of the white box I'm adding the listing to so I can center it, or figure out any other way of pulling this off. Heres the first bit of code with and without the one line revision. Thank you for your time and patience, I did look for this on other threads and couldnt find anything exact, i did try a few and nothing worked. Please help! :) Thanks!

```
<meta content="text/html; charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type"><title>Untitled 1</title><style type="text/css">
.auto-style1 {
background-color: #3A3428;
}
.auto-style2 {
text-align: center;
}
.auto-style13 {
background-color: #3A3428;
}
.auto-style10 {
text-align: left;
}
.auto-style12 {
text-align: center;
}
.auto-style11 {
vertical-align: middle;
}
h1 {
font-family:Cambria, "Hoefler Text", "Liberation Serif", Times, "Times New Roman", serif;
font-size:22px;
font-weight:bold;
}
.auto-style5 {
font-size: 16pt;
}
.auto-style7 {
text-align: right;
}
.auto-style9 {
font-size: 20pt;
text-align: left;
}
.auto-style8 {
font-size: 20pt;
}
.auto-style14 {
font-size: 24pt;
text-align: center;
}
.auto-style15 {
font-size: 12pt;
text-align: center;
}
.auto-style16 {
font-size: 12pt;
}
</style><table class="auto-style1" style="text-align: center; width: 1130px; height: 2200px;"><tbody><tr><td class="auto-style2" valign="top"><table width="749" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="text-align: left;"><tbody><tr><td width="749" class="auto-style13"><img
```

image source removed because im a noob lol.

EDIT: Alright - I've made some slight progress. I went ahead and added a container based code with a length and width of 1200px ea. I then entered in the Div centered code and it seemed to have worked! BUT ONLY on internet explorer???? lol *CRIES* its still a giant sea of white on Chrome, but perfect on IE. OH dear? :( Looking forward to some advice - thank you to anyone!!

Screenie on IE: http://gyazo.com/75a67d313f92573b81c2fe8e7fbff192

Screenie on Chrome: http://gyazo.com/15c8d7455d6f2e10b968f6b09f04da69

IE is perfect!! Chrome is screwed??? Whats up here lol. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to create a wrapper that is 100% width, then an inner than is fixed width with margin set to auto, and float everything inside this.  This has always worked for me and I build these for a living.  The floating keeps the iframe the correct height, the wrapper and inner keep it centered.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="inner">
        <div id="header">...</div>
        <div id="content">...</div>
        <div id="footer">...</div>
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    #wrapper {width:100%;float:left;}
    #inner {width:960px;margin:auto;}
    #footer, #content, #header {width:960px;float:left;}
</style>
```